# PHP form will not work after removing file names from URL

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I am using a php script to send the input from a form to an email for my wedding. When the user submits the form from rsvp.php, it redirects to the script file, send_form_email.php  It worked perfectly until I modified my .htaccess file to eliminate file names from my website URLs. Now when I press submit on the rsvp.php page, it redirects to send_form_url.php, but is a blank screen instead of the confirmation message. Why is this happening? Is there a way to get my php script to work while removing the file extensions, or a way to remove the file extension from every url except the one with the php script? My .htaccess file is below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .html
```

Comment: Do you mean that your form's `action` is set to `send_form_email.php`? Or do you mean that PHP redirects to that page after processing the form?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you might be rewriting `send_form_email.php` to `send_form_email`, which isn't found. Instead, try skipping that first rule by setting your form action to `send_form_email`, which should be rewritten to `send_form_email.php`. Maybe?